# Page not found error in django where it is not supposed to rise

Tags: python, django

I am building a video player app in django. But, when going to the register route, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/users/login/%7B%25%20url%20'register'%20%7D
```

I don't even have a url called `users/login/register`. And I have checked my `urls.py`. Here it is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

And here is the link that leads to this route:

```
<a href="{% url 'register' }">Register</a>
```

I have built many apps with django but have never encountered an error like this. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a % in your a tag, it should be

```
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

probably, url is not recognized because of absence "%" before brace in the last line.

```
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
```